# How to obtain GridSearchCV partly finished results?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikits

I have started a grid search for SVM parameters in a rather wide range.

The most of the search space have been calculated and now I got one last process, which goes already for 100 hours.

I'd like to see the results, that already have been calculated.
Is there any way to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the current `GridSearchCV` implementation has no async / background mode. However you can implement your own [custom scorer object](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-score-functions) to save the partial results to a database or some files on the disk to monitor the progress.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `verbose` option to a value `>0`. That will at least give you the results on stdout.

Comment: Thanks, that will be useful, but the process is already running.

Comment: Just to add: if you are using IPython Notebook, the output is in the IPython terminal window, not in the interactive session.